# Is it possible to identify source of laptop noise?

Tags: sound, hard-drive, fan

My laptop makes a very unobtrusive whirring noise every few seconds, and I'd like to know whether it is just a fan, or the hard drive spinning up. If the latter I'll look in to power management settings for the hard drive, but lacking experience I can't be sure what the cause is.

Are there real time terminal commands which would allow me to see if hard drive or fan access coincides with the noise?

Comment: For the hard drive you'll see the LED activity light flicker. For the fan hold year hand near the exhaust port and you'll feel the air move.

Comment: Its certainly blowing out hot air, which sometimes, but not always seems to correspond with hard drive activity (LED flicker). Think I'll stop worrying about it! Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention most wurring comes from Ubuntu Live DVD.